# Using a table variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have designed a small query for table variable. This is the code:

```
DECLARE @TESTTABLE TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(40))

INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE 
VALUES (1, 'WALLEY'), (2, 'BARRY'), (3, 'TIM'),
       (4, 'DICK'), (5, 'BRUCE')
```

My question is SQL allows use of alias for table variable like in the below query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM @TESTTABLE t 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_DETAILS ON t.ID = BusinessEntityID
```

But you cannot use the actual table variable name like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @TESTTABLE 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_DETAILS ON @TESTTABLE.ID = BusinessEntityID
```

The above query shows an error.

Does anyone have an answer for this? Would be really helpful.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I've fixed your code. FYI, the way to show code is to put a blank line, and then indent each line of code four spaces. If you edit your post, you'll see what i've done.

Comment: What error are you seeing when you run the code? Instinctively I'd suggest that you use aliases and see if it helps, something like `SELECT * FROM @TESTTABLE tt INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_DETAILS emp_d  ON tt.ID = emp_d.BusinessEntityID`

Comment: Hi, your question isn't very clear. As well as including the details of the DBMS and error message, could you clarify what you actually want to know? You seem to already know a way to make the query work (use an alias). Are you looking for something shorter? Or do you just want to understand *why* it doesn't work?

Comment: In any case, I think it's mostly universal that database objects (like tables) have to be static. So if you want it parametrized you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Error_2646 This isn't a parameterised query, the variable doesn't just hold the table name, it *is* the table; essentially a different type of temporary table.

Comment: It seems that you have to give the table variable an alias in order to refer to it later in the statement.  It's probably just a fact.  It isn't a problem to use an alias though.

Comment: This may not be directly related but if your dataset is large, consider using a temp table instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In T-SQL, you need to use aliases when joining variable tables.

Reference : https://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx (see section : Restrictions)

It should give you something like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM @TESTTABLE tt 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_DETAILS emp_d 
ON tt.ID = emp_d.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: This does not appear to be true.  Do you have a Microsoft reference?

Comment: From [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) "Outside a FROM clause, table variables must be referenced by using an alias"

Comment: @GarethLyons But this ***is in*** a `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GarethLyons Also, I've tested my solution outside of the FROM clause and it still works.  Either there's a bug in the SQL Server parser or the Doc is wrong.

Comment: @RBarryYoung from what I can tell from the original post, it works when it is in the `FROM` clause, but not in the `JOIN / ON`. That's also what the documentation suggests. Can't quite test it myself at the moment though.

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's in the ON clause, not the FROM. The example on the MS page is that of a join. Your solution works too, although honestly I was surprised it does! I haven't seen table variables referenced like that before in mssql.

Comment: @GarethLyons `ON` is part of the `FROM` clause.  It is not "*outside of the FROM clause*".

Comment: @RBarryYoung to be fair, I mostly agree with you on that :)

Answer (score 2):

Use "[..]" to quote the table variable's name.  This works for me:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @TESTTABLE INNER JOIN 
     EMPLOYEE_DETAILS
     ON [@TESTTABLE].ID = BusinessEntityID
```

That said, I would probably prefer to use an alias, or just use a CTE and forego the table variable altogether.

Comment: Thnx for the reply. But his is not working. I am getting the below error.
The multi-part identifier "@TESTTABLE.ID" could not be bound.